# Article Price: A Methodical Approach

Tags: arithmetic, puzzle

From *Mathematics For Pleasure Paperback* by Oswald Jacoby and William H. Benson (1965)

> A certain article costs an amount which requires a minimum of four
>   standard United States coins to pay for it. To purchase two of these
>   articles would require a minimum of six coins. However, three of the
>   article can be purchased for two coins. W*hat is the price of the
>   article?*

The solution simply states that:

> A little quick figuring will show that the article costs seventeen
>   cents.
>
> 17 cents: 2 cents + 1 nickel + 1 dime = 4 coins
>
> 34 cents: 4 cents + 1 nickel + 1 quarter = 6 coins
>
> 51 cents: 1 cent + 1 half dollar = 2 coins

**My question:**

Except trial and error, what would be a methodical way to approach a problem such as this?

Comment: Any thoughts about my answer?

Comment: @Gerry Thanks for your answer. Your answer shows one way (albeit a thoughtful one) to think about the problem. But I want to know whether there is a methodical approach or not. I need more than “probably inescapable.”

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "methodical". The brute force approach of first trying one cent, then trying two cents, then three, and so on – that's methodical, but it's also the epitome of trial and error, as it's trialling every possibility, and discarding all the errors. So what do you actually want?

Comment: @Gerry I just want to know whether it is at all possible to approach except trial and error.

Comment: OK, so, why do you *need* more than "probably inescapable"? What's the context here? It's just something somebody wrote 50 years ago in a mass market paperback – what's the importance?

Comment: Are you still here, blackened?

Answer (score 1):

Some trial and error is probably inescapable, but perhaps it can be minimized.

The coins are 1, 5, 10, 25, and 50. Considering the 3rd condition, we need two of these to add up to a multiple of three. The only possibilities are $1+5=3\times2$, $1+50=3\times17$, $5+10=3\times5$, $5+25=3\times10$, $10+50=3\times20$, and $25+50=3\times25$. So you just have 6 cases to look at. Now go to the 2nd condition. Do you need six coins for any of 4, 34, 10, 20, 40, 50? Yes, but only for 34, so that's the only possible answer.